# get the correct signature of method

Tags: java, android, bitmap, frida

Here's what I want to achieve: I want to see exactly what parameters + arguments a method uses. This is how I proceeded:

1. Find the call with frida-trace: `frida-trace -U -F -j '*!setImageBitmap'`

Log 1:

```
 14227 ms  AppCompatImageView.setImageBitmap("<instance: android.graphics.Bitmap>")
 14227 ms     | ImageView.setImageBitmap("<instance: android.graphics.Bitmap>")
```

2. Now i use the following hook script

```
Java.perform(() =>{
    const cl = Java.use('androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView')

    cl.setImageBitmap.implementation = function(arg) {
        console.log("this : " + this)
        console.log("arg : " + arg)

        this.setImageBitmap(arg)

    }
})
```

Now I get the following output:

Log 2:

```
this : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView{e9b4cb7 V.QD..... ......MA 681,37-992,344 #7f0a05ee app:id/whatever}
arg : android.graphics.Bitmap@6099c24
```

3. Try passing my own bitmap type:

```
Java.perform(() =>{
    const cl = Java.use('androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView')
    const bm = Java.use('android.graphics.Bitmap')

    cl.setImageBitmap.implementation = function(arg) {
        console.log("this : " + this)
        console.log("arg : " + arg)
    
    // define bitmap
        let newBitmap = bm.$new()
        let newBitmap2 = bm.$new(100, 100, newBitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

        this.setImageBitmap(newBitmap2)
    }
})
```

I get the following error message:

Log 3:

```
Error: Bitmap(): argument types do not match any of:
    .overload('long', 'int', 'int', 'int', 'boolean', 'boolean', '[B', 'android.graphics.NinePatch$InsetStruct')
    at X (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:622)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:1141)
    at e (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:606)
    at <anonymous> (/home/besc/work/fickBB/frieda-trace/snippets/traceThisTest.js:9)
    at apply (native)
    at ne (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:673)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:651)
```

1. Question:
   Is the interpretation of the output of frieda-trace (Log 1) correct, the method `setImageBitmap` expects 1 argument with type `android.graphics.Bitmap`?
2. Question:
   Is the interpretation of the output from the frieda hook script (Log 2) correct that the argument passed to the method `setImageBitmap` is everything between the curly brackets, i.e. this:
   `e9b4cb7 V.QD..... ......MA 681,37-992,344 #7f0a05ee app:id/whatever`

is this an argument? Or more? If it is one, then this should be an `android.graphics.Bitmap`, right? But to me that looks like 6 arguments (    `.overload('long', 'int', 'int', 'int', 'boolean', 'boolean', '[B', 'android.graphics.NinePatch$InsetStruct')`) If yes, then `frida-trace` is wrong, why?

3. Question:
   Is the interpretation of the output from the frieda hook script (Log 2) correct that the output of arg is a pointer to the bitmap (`@6099c24`)? If yes, how can I access/view it, since the value I'm looking for is probably there, right?

Comment: The `arg` argument is usually an array, even for single argument methods. If you want to see the method argument types decompile the APK. Load it in Jadx-gui, go to the method you want to hook and let Frida generate the Frida snippet for the method using the context menu.